# Assign variables while disregarding capitalization

Tags: php, variables

Hi can anyone tell me how to assign variables disregarding whether how the capitalization was used

if(place == "new york")

NeW YoRk or nEW yORK should also work instead of only new york. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this PHP? If so, try this:

```
if (strtolower($place) == 'new york') {
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php